# My child stands with her feet on my feet, I hold her hands to balance, I walk and move her. Is it ok to say "She's walking on my feet"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

My child stands with her feet on my feet, I hold her hands with my hands to keep balance, then I walk and thus move her along as shown in the picture.

Is it correct to say "**She's walking on my feet**"?

Comment: The grammar's fine but the expression is a bit misleading. I can't think of an exact expression. She is resting her feet on yours in order to walk in tandem with you. (You hold her hands to secure/balance **her**.)

Comment: [***Walking on dads feet***](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMN3q9bokAk) - YouTube. Should have been ***Dad's** feet*, but we'll let that pass.

Comment: Yep, that's right. People say it.